# Abort output in currently executing command in shell mode

Tags: comint, shell-mode, grep

Sometimes in shell I end up executing a command which results in too much output.

For example, consider a wrong `grep` on a huge text file which results in 10,000 matches. The `grep` command completes quickly, but Emacs updates the shell buffer slowly and it takes forever to complete.

At that point I would like for Emacs to abort the output and return to the shell prompt. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Currently I kill the shell process (bash) and start it again in the same buffer, but it would be nice to not have to do that

Comment: Could you give a recipe showing the scenario - just what you do, step by step?

Comment: How about trying `C-c C-c`, which is bound to `comint-interrupt-subjob` -- does that suffice to stop/break your running process output?

Comment: I understood he said that its only the output that is slow - the command and process have finished. Emacs is taking time to process the output buffer.

Comment: C-c C-c doesn't work. I run into this issue all the time, I just kill the shell buffer and restart what I was doing. I'd love to know how to get shell to just chill out.

Comment: What @JordonBiondo said. 

I do exactly the same thing. I know there is an output filter function so I am hoping something can be done there to stop writing to buffer